# combine csv files, sort them by time and average the colums

Tags: pandas, merge, average

I have many datasets in csv files they look like in the picture that I attached.

In the first column is always the time in minutes, but the time steps and the total number of rows differ between the raw data files. I'd like to have one output file (csv file) in which all the raw files are combined and sorted by the time. So that the time increases from the top to the bottom of the column.

[raw data and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9MDu.png)

The concentration column should be averaged, when more than one number exists.

I tried like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = pd.read_csv('dat1.txt', sep="\t")
d2 = pd.read_csv('dat2.txt', sep="\t")

d1.columns
d2.columns

merged_outer = pd.merge(d1,d2, on='time', how='outer')
print merged_outer
```

but it doesn't lead to the correct output. I'm a beginner in Pandas but I hope I explaind the problem well enough. Thank you for any idea or suggestion!

---

Thank you for your idea. Unfortunately, when I run it I get an error message saying that dat1.txt doesn't exist. This seems strange to me as I read the raw files initially by:

```
d1 = pd.read_csv('dat1.txt', sep="\t")
d2 = pd.read_csv('dat2.txt', sep="\t")
```

Sorry, here the data as raw text:

```
raw data 1 
time    column2 column3 concentration
1   2   4   3
2   2   4   6
4   2   4   2
7   2   4   5


raw data 2 
time    column2 column3 concentration
1   2   4   6
2   2   4   2
8   2   4   9
10  2   4   5
12  2   4   7
```

Comment: next time you ask a question, paste excepts of the raw text of the `csv` file, instead of screenshots, then other people can more easily test their code

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work

```
filenames = ['dat1.txt', 'dat2.txt',...]
dataframes = {filename: pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t") for filename in filenames}

merged_outer = pd.concat(dataframes).groupby('time').mean()
```

When you pass a dict to `pd.concat`, it creates a MultiIndex DataFrame with the dict keys as level0